# In IEEEtran, how does changing the section number style through `\thesectiondis` work?

Tags: pdftex, ieeetran

We change the section number style in the general document class by modifying `\thesection`. However, in IEEEtran, we need to change the section number style by modifying `\thesectiondis`. However, I cannot find the definition of `\sectiondis` counter in `IEEEtran.cls`. Curious about how the `\thesectiondis` works.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand{\thesectiondis}{oo\thesection qq}
\renewcommand{\thesubsectiondis}{tt\Alph{subsection}kk}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsectiondis}{xx\arabic{subsubsection}yy}
\begin{document}
\section{xxxx}
\subsection{xxxx}
\subsubsection{xxxx}
\subsubsection{xxxx}
\subsection{xxxx}
\subsubsection{xxxx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The counter is still `section` (or `\c@section`) and `\thesection` still works.  `\thesectiondis` is simply a macro used by `\section` to display the section number (there, and only there).

Comment: @JohnKormylo How can we find the macro definition of `\section` which contains `\thesectiondis` in `IEEEtran`?

Comment: First, you need to find where the source code is stored.  On my computer I found it in `C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\ieeetrantools`,  It has several different definitions, depending on CLASSOPTION.  Try `\meaning\thesectiondis` to find which one is being used.

Comment: You wanted the definition of `\section`, which also has variations but all seem to use `\@startsection` which AFAIK dose NOT use \thesectiondis (`\csname the#1\endcsname`).

Comment: Actually, the only time I see `\thesectiondis` being used is in regard to appendices.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, you are right. Only `\@IEEEprocessthesectionargument` contains `\thesectiondis` in `IEEEtran.cls`. I still don't know how `\thesectiondis` works.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I found I can use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{oo\Roman{section}qq}` to change section number style. But I cannot use `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{tt\Alph{subsection}kk}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{xx\arabic{subsubsection}yy}` to change subsection and subsubsection number style. Why?